# Regex starts with, contains, and ends with

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to create a regular expression that is to be integrated in monitoring services. They are validated using golang regex.

So I was trying to create a regex that validates java exceptions.
For example I have these exceptions (they are seperate lines)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ...

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: ...
```

And I need a regular expressions that accepts **exceptions** only. Not errors, nor other types.

I'm able to catch java messages with this regular expression

```
pattern: "^java.lang"
```

But that also includes all types of errors, which is not intent.
I was trying to make the regex to catch the word "exception" at the end, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Are you asking what regex you should do or how you shoud do it? i'm not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could match any character zero or more times no greedy and then match Exception: `.*?Exception:` after `^java\.lang\.` .

`^java\.lang\..*?Exception:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Wf2S9/1)

Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

Comment: I'm trying to make it compatible with the "Inputs and Patterns" section [here](https://github.com/carlpett/stream_exporter), specifically in the 'pattern' field, with this regex... but not being able to

Comment: Do you get an error or are you sure there are exceptions? Did you try`pattern: "^java\.lang\..*?Exception:"`?